# SCCM - SQL Server Invalid Column Name

Tags: sql, sccm

I upgraded my SCCM 1511, then I attached the data from old database to new database. My SCCM couldn't connect to site database. I viewed the `smsprov.log` and saw these error messages. Can anyone help please?

```
Execute SQL =select  all SMS_Identification.License,SMS_Identification.LocaleID,SMS_Identification.DaysLeft,SMS_Identification.ServiceAccountName,SMS_Identification.SMSAvailableConsoleVersion,SMS_Identification.SMSBuildNumber,SMS_Identification.SMSMinBuildNumber,SMS_Identification.SMSProviderServer,SMS_Identification.SMSSiteServer,SMS_Identification.SMSVersion,SMS_Identification.ThisSiteCode,SMS_Identification.ThisSiteName,SMS_Identification.UIManifestHash,SMS_Identification.UIManifestHashAlgorithm from vSMSData AS SMS_Identification ~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.930+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
*** [42S22][207][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'SMSAvailableConsoleVersion'.  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.982+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
~*~*~[42S22][207][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'SMSAvailableConsoleVersion'.     ThreadID : 15724 , DbError: 207 , Sev: 16~*~*~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.982+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
*** [42S22][207][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'UIManifestHash'.  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.982+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
~*~*~[42S22][207][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'UIManifestHash'.   [42S22][207][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'SMSAvailableConsoleVersion'.  ThreadID : 15724 , DbError: 207 , Sev: 16~*~*~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.982+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
*** [42S22][207][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'UIManifestHashAlgorithm'.  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.983+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
~*~*~[42S22][207][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'UIManifestHashAlgorithm'.   [42S22][207][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'UIManifestHash'.  ThreadID : 15724 , DbError: 207 , Sev: 16~*~*~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.983+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
Results returned : 0 of -1~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.983+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
<*><*> CANT CONNECT TO SQL, RETURNING ERROR <*><*>~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.984+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
Found IClassManger: Opal SMS CSsp Provider Extension Implementation.~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.984+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
CExtUserContext::LeaveThread : Releasing IWbemContextPtr=803762080~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:20.984+420><thread=15724 (0x3D6C)>
SMSPROV DllMain - DLL_PROCESS_DETACH...calling  AfxTermExtensionModule~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:51.282+420><thread=21708 (0x54CC)>
EXTNPROV DllMain DLL_PROCESS_DETACH~  $$<SMS Provider><06-24-2016 08:41:51.285+420><thread=21708 (0x54CC)>
```

Comment: Have you attempted to verify your column names at all in the vSMSData table?  Are they SMSAvailableConsoleVersion, UIManifestHash, etc or are they something else?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like the database was corrupted, try to restore another good backup of SCCM database if you have. If not, to check smsprov.log, i suppose there are other errors regarding failure to connect database, check the table one by one.